# Is it possible to add an action to the currently running action?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, hooks, actions, wp-register-script

My question is very simple but I haven't found this answer yet. Here's an example:

```
class MyClass {
  public function __construct(){
    add_action('init', array($this, 'init'));
    add_action('wp_footer', array($this, 'footer'));
  }

  public function init(){
    add_action('init', array($this, 'register_scripts'));
  }

  public function register_scripts(){
    wp_register_script('my-script', plugins_url('/script.js', __FILE__));
  }

  public function footer(){
    echo('<div class="style-me">Rawr this is my plugin.</div>');
  }
}
```

This is how my code looks and it's failing. It displays the div but the javascript does not get applied. So I wondered if my problem was running the `init()` function in the init action and then adding `register_scripts()` to the init action but I'm already in that action. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use a later (higher) priority. So use `current_filter()` to get the current hook and priority, add 1 to that priority, and register the next action:

```
add_action( 'init', 'func_1' );

function func_1()
{
    global $wp_filter;

    $hook = current_filter();
    add_action( $hook, 'func_2', key( $wp_filter[ $hook ] ) + 1 );
}

function func_2()
{
    echo 'hi!';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is probably the problem. Why are you using this approach?

Why not just do the following?

```
public function init(){
     wp_register_script('my-script', plugins_url('/script.js', __FILE__));
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but in version 4.7, WordPress changed how they handled hooks, so the answer above will no longer work.

The relevant difference is in the `my-functions.php` file which contains a function that will return the current priority of a hook for versions before and after 4.7.

( Note: I don't like adding hooks in the constructor, so I've taken the liberty to structure the plugin a little differently, but it will work the same. )

In my-plugin.php:

```
require_once( PATH_TO . '/my-functions.php' );
require_once( PATH_TO . '/my-class.php' );

add_action( 'plugins_loaded', [ new MyClass(), 'register' ] );
```

In my-functions.php:

```
if( ! functions_exists( 'current_priority' ) ):
function current_priority() {
  global $wp_filter;
  global $wp_version;
  return version_compare( $wp_version, '4.7', '<' ) ?
    key( $wp_filter[ current_filter() ] ) :
    $wp_filter[ current_filter() ]->current_priority();
}
endif;
```

In myclass.php:

```
class MyClass {

  public function register() {
    add_action( 'init', [ $this, 'init' ] );
    add_action( 'wp_footer', [ $this, 'footer' ] );
  }

  public function init(){
    //* Add action to current filter at the next priority
    add_action( current_filter(), [ $this, 'register_scripts' ], current_priority() + 1 );
  }

  public function register_scripts(){
    wp_register_script( 'my-script', plugins_url( '/script.js', __FILE__) );
  }

  public function footer(){
    echo( '<div class="style-me">Rawr this is my plugin.</div>' );
  }
}
```